# Swift / Objective C: How to get value from object by string name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

```
class A {
  var x = 1
}

var a = A()
```

How to get a variable "x" from object "a" using string name ( a["x"] )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work if the class inherits from `NSObject`, where you can use `valueForKey:` to get at the properties.

```
import Foundation

class A: NSObject {
  var x = 1
}

let a = A()
let aval = a.valueForKey("x")
println("\(aval)")
```

Note that `aval` is an `AnyObject?` here since there's no type information. You'll need to cast it or test what it is yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [gregheo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588402/1023981), if you want to use the subscript syntax like the example in your question, you can do so by implementing `subscript`.

```
class A: NSObject {
    var x = 1

    subscript(key: String) -> Int {
        get {
            return self.valueForKey(key) as Int
        }
        set {
            self.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

var a = A()
println(a["x"])
a["x"] = 5
println(a["x"])
```